# Are github keywords case sensitive?

Tags: github

We can do things like [automatically close an issue from a commit message](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/closing-issues-using-keywords) by using certain keywords.

Are these keywords case sensitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else who arrives here, the answer is: github keywords are **not** case sensitive (`close` and `Close` will both work)